# javascript to verify email from this website

Tags: javascript, ios

I don't know any javascript, but I need some javascript code I can run within my iPhone app to verify if an email address is real.

**I know this isn't a good approach, but I'd still like to see how this would be done in javascript**

Here is what I am doing:

```
- (BOOL)verifyEmailAddress:(NSString *)address
{
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://verify-email.org/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

    NSString *javascriptString = @" ... ";   // this should be javascript code

    NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptString];
    if ([javascriptString isEqualToString:@"OK"])
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

The code should probably do it like this:

1. Enter the variable `address` into the field:
   [image: input field]
2. Press the verify button:
   [image: button]
3. Check the result. 
   [image: result]
4. Return a string that says "OK" or "Bad"

How do I do this?

Comment: There is a python script to hack the verify-email.org http://gist.github.com/arulrajnet/eaecf393eebd57264e09 you can replicate in javascript

Comment: Why would you implement this if none of my emails are working here? I used custom domains which i setup correctly through google admin / hotmail and also used an icloud email. It only searching for mx records which seems not legit to check wether an emailbox actually exists.